# Using multiple authorization types on a single appsync request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, serverless, aws-appsync

As per AWS documentation, Appsync now supports the usage of multiple authorization types to allow some fields to be queried using only the default authorization type(ie. api_key), and other fields to be accessed only with the secondary auth type(ie. cognito_user_pools).

However I have been unable to setup my appsync graphql api to make a certain type retrievable only if the users request has BOTH of the authorization types, in my case those would be api_key and aws_iam. Api_key is the primary authorization type, and iam is the additional one.

Is this even possible to implement, or can one request use only one authorization type?

Example code below:

```
type Car @aws_api_key @aws_iam {
  id: ID!
  year: Int
  color: String
  tireType: String
}

type Query {
  getCar(id: ID!): Car @aws_api_key @aws_iam
}
```

The end result should be the retrieval of the Car type only if the user request has both the api-key header and the signaturev4 authorization header indicating that the request is properly signed.

I tried adding both authorization types in the appsync GQL setup and attaching the proper conditions to the types I want authorized, but it does not provide the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I use that exact syntax to specify an "OR" relationship between authorization types.  You would have to create a custom resolver to check for an "AND" relationship, and then your resolver wouldn't match your schema.  You should consider whether you really need "AND".  IAM authentication is typically much more secure than an API key.